# How to Insert Php into jQuery show

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Hello i'm trying to insert

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

into the jQuery show function below, but it doesn't work. Is it even possible to insert the php function into jQuery?
     *update

```
<head> 
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>; 
</head> 
<button>Show it</button> 
<a style="display: none"><?php comments_template(); ?></a> 
<script>
$("button").click(function () { $("a").show("slow"); }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Please show us how you are inserting it.

Comment: where are you trying to insert it? I don't see anything

Comment: You haven't closed your head tag. also, you need to show the HTML and then `.hide()` it on `$("document").ready()`

Comment: I've just been inserting it like so....

Comment: head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  </head
  <button>Show it</button>
  <a style="display: none"><?php comments_template(); ?></a>
 <script>
$("button").click(function () {
$("a").show("slow");
});
</script

Comment: @Julian Like _what_, you don't have any php code inserted in what you gave us.  Show us what it is before the render..

Comment: Add it to the question, not the comments.

Answer (score 1):

May be if your comments_template returns its result as a string, instead of directly printing it with echo, you just need something like this:

```
<?php echo comments_template(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make your `comments_template()` return a full string.

Then, try structuring your code like this. You want to `.hide()` the comments on `.ready()`, and then `.show()` them when you click the `.comment-button` button.

```
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="comment-button">Show Comments</button>
  <p class="comments"><?php echo comments_template(); ?></p>
  <script>
    $("document").ready(function() {
      $(".comments").hide();
      $(".comment-button").click(function () {
        $(".comments").show("slow");
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Don't use direct elements with `$()` in jQuery, either; use a class or an ID.

Also, if you want a **brilliant** framework to use that can collapse elements with subtle animations, try [Bootstrap for Twitter](http://getbootstrap.com) and then do something like this:

```
<div class="comment-1 collapse">
  <?php echo comments_template(); ?>
</div>
<button data-target=".comment-1" data-toggle="collapse">Show Comment</button>
```

No Javascript needed, since it's already in the bootstrap library.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but still no dice here is a link http://codmemes.com/test/ (NSFW)

Comment: You know, you could pick something a little bit better for a testing page. Also, you are hiding the wrong elements. Use a class.

Comment: I apologize for the image I just removed it..... What do you mean by using a class?